# yum - separate proxies connection to non proxies

Tags: rhel, yum, proxy, repository

On my RHEL7 server, I have:

- RHEL repositories on a local server
- Other repositories on the net (EPEL, etc)

When I run yum, I would like to use my proxy server only for external repositories (or for wget) but not on my "local" repos.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum.conf` allows you to have per-repository settings as well as global (`[main]`) settings, so either:

1. unset the global proxy setting and have a proxy setting for each of your external repositories.

or

2. have a global default proxy setting, but set `proxy=_none_` for your local repositories.

See `man yum.conf` for more details.

For `wget`, you can use the `no_proxy` environment variable.  From `man wget`:

> no_proxy
>
> This variable should contain a comma-separated list of domain extensions proxy should not be used for.  For instance, if the value of no_proxy is .mit.edu, proxy will not be used to retrieve documents from MIT.